# JQuery - Homepage slide animation on page load, but only once for each viewer

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

What's the best way to slide two divs into each other.  Basically, I split my homepage into two sections.  I want them to slide down and slide up into each other, but happen only once for each viewer.

```
<div id="wrap">
 <div id="slideDown">Slide down</div>
 <div id="slideUp">Slide up</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The best way would be to write some code...

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it happen only once for each viewer?

Comment: Do you mean if a visitor comes to your site, they will see the animation ONLY the first time they visit? All other subsequent visits will show the website sans animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to use jQuery's animation effects `slideUp` and `slideDown` (see tandu's answer) or just use [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) if you're feeling more verbose.

But, in order to stop the browser from executing this animation on a return visit, you're going to need to store a cookie. The [jquery-cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) is a good place to start. Basically what you're going to want to do is:

1. Check for presence of doNotLoadAnimation cookie.
2. If not present, set doNotLoadAnimation cookie and show animation, else show the page w/o the animation

It isn't going to be perfect because cookies aren't a form of persistent storage, e.g. if a user clears their cookies, the animation will execute again.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.slideUp` and `.slideDown` hide and show content by sliding, respectively.  In order to have `.slideUp` actually show content, you have to use jQuery UI show effect for slide, as in:

```
$("#slideUp").show( 'slide', {direction: 'up'} );
```

It's hard to tell exactly what you want, though, and if you just paste what I have there (assuming you have the effects UI) it will only trigger once for each view.

Comment: He'd need to set a cookie somewhere if my comment on his post is true.